# In Jeff Wayne's War of the Worlds, what happens to Parson Nathaniel to render him unconscious?

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

In The Spirit of Man, Parson Nathaniel has the line:

> Nathaniel : Those machines are just demons in another form. I shall
>   destroy them with my prayers, I shall burn them with my holy cross. I
>   shall...

And then *clunk*, he just falls over unconscious. Is it explained anywhere what actually caused this to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Journalist hit him in the face**. Presumably this was intended to stop him from running outside screaming and giving away their hiding place.

---

As Joe L. has pointed out in a comment, in the original [source novel](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/www/warworlds/b2c4.html) he was hit in the head with the handle-end of a meat cleaver.

> "I have been still too long," he said, in a tone that must have
> reached the pit, "and now I must bear my witness. Woe unto this
> unfaithful city! Woe! Woe! Woe! Woe! Woe! To the inhabitants of the
> earth by reason of the other voices of the trumpet----"
>
> "Shut up!" I said, rising to my feet, and in a terror lest the
> Martians should hear us. "For God's sake----"
>
> "Nay," shouted the curate, at the top of his voice, standing likewise
> and extending his arms. "Speak! The word of the Lord is upon me!"
>
> In three strides he was at the door leading into the kitchen.
>
> "I must bear my witness! I go! It has already been too long delayed."
>
> I put out my hand and felt the meat chopper hanging to the wall. In a
> flash I was after him. I was fierce with fear. **Before he was halfway
> across the kitchen I had overtaken him. With one last touch of
> humanity I turned the blade back and struck him with the butt.** He went
> headlong forward and lay stretched on the ground. I stumbled over him
> and stood panting. He lay still.

Comment: Here's the same scene in the book: "I put out my hand and felt the meat chopper hanging to the wall. In a flash I was after him. I was fierce with fear. Before he was halfway across the kitchen I had overtaken him. With one last touch of humanity I turned the blade back and struck him with the butt. He went headlong forward and lay stretched on the ground. I stumbled over him and stood panting. He lay still."

Comment: @JoeL. - Cheers for the assist. Added with gratitude.